# pandas split column text into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, split

How can I split the column value into 2 new columns:

Data:

```
WO No
OR-20180422-12345
```

Input:

```
df[['CO','WO Date',WO ID']] = df.pop('WO No').str.split('-', expand=True)
```

Expected output:

```
 CO     WO Date #as dd/mm/yyyy date format
 OR     22/04/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way using vectorised functionality.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'WO No': ['OR-20180422-12345']})

df[['CO', 'WO Date', 'WO ID']] = df['WO No'].str.split('-', expand=True)

df['WO Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['WO Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df = df[['CO', 'WO Date']]

print(df)

#    CO     WO Date
# 0  OR  22/04/2018
```

Comment: This solution is better, as it avoids `apply`. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rule(a):
    vals = a.split("-")
    d = pd.to_datetime(vals[1])
    d = d.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') # your format 
    return pd.Series({"C0": vals[0], "W0 Date": d})

df["W0 No"].apply(rule)
```

Output

```
    C0  W0 Date
0   OR  22/04/2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split`:

```
def split_it(s):
    return pd.Series({'CO': s[0], 'WO Date': pd.to_datetime(s[1])})
>>> df['WO no'].str.split('-').apply(split_it)
    CO  WO Date
0   OR  2018-04-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
s = pd.Series(data="OR-20180422-12345")
```

Use extractall

```
df = str.extractall("(?P<CO>[A-Z]{2})-(?P<WOdate>\d{8})-\d+").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Cleanup dtypes:

```
df['WOdate'] = df['WOdate'].apply(pd.to_datetime);df
```

Out:

```
   CO     WOdate
0  OR 2018-04-22
```